# Useing modulemap is in the swift framework to bridge the OC, and the missing required module is reported in project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I created a swift framework, and created a module.modulemap file, and included a Test.h file.

```
module Test {
    header "Test.h"
    export *
}
```

Then I set the import path in swift complier - Search Path like this

```
${SRCROOT}/SwiftFramework
```

Next I used this Test file in the swift file.

```
import Test

public class SwiftFramework: NSObject {
    @objc public class func test() {
        Test.test()
    }
}
```

I created a project, added swiftframework, and it can run successfully. But when I change a computer or send the framework to someone else to use, will report 'Missing required module 'Test'' in project, The xcode version is the same，how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently (swift frameworks) and it seems like there's no way around this at the moment. This is a lot easier to deal with if there's a dependency manager involved (eg cocoapods) coz it will implicitly resolve those dependencies.

This is also the case with Facebook's iOS SDK. Eg: If you include FBSDKLoginKit as a pod, it will also fetch `FBSDKCore`. But if you include `FBSDKLoginKit.framework` in your project, it will complain that `FBSDKCore` wasn't found.
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk